# Why does this example of validation not work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial, we are currently making a `user` creation form. We need to validate that the email is unique. We've done so using `validates :uniqueness` for this. He then mentions the following:

Using validates :uniqueness does not guarantee uniqueness.

> D’oh! But what can go wrong? Here’s what:
>
> 1. Alice signs up for the sample app, with address alice@wonderland.com.
> 2. Alice accidentally clicks on “Submit” twice, sending two requests in quick succession.
> 3. The following sequence occurs: request 1 creates a user in memory that passes validation, request 2 does the same, request 1’s
>      user gets saved, request 2’s user gets saved.
> 4. Result: two user records with the exact same email address, despite the uniqueness validation.

"If the above sequence seems implausible, believe me, it isn’t: it can happen on any Rails website with significant traffic. Luckily, the solution is straightforward to implement; we just need to enforce uniqueness at the database level as well. Our method is to create a database index on the email column, and then require that the index be unique."

If i'm not mistaken, doesnt the validation check occur after rails attempts to save the object? Since object 1 is saved first, shouldn't object 2 fail to save?

He also claims "we just need to enforce uniqueness at the database level as well", by creating a "database index" on the email column, and checking that instead. Why does that work while the email check doesn't, I feel as if they wouldn't be any different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving a record with a uniqueness validation will issue two SQL requests:

- One to the database to make sure that unique value (ie. `alice@wonderland.com`) isn't already present
- And then one to save the record, if all validations succeed.

What happens if, in between that first and second query, someone else tries to sign up with that email address? If you have a busy site running in multiple processes, lots of requests can happen simultaneously so this is a plausible scenario.

- The first request checks that `alice@wonderland.com` isn't present - it isn't, so the validation passes.
- The second request checks that `alice@wonderland.com` isn't present - it isn't, so the validation passes.
- The first request then saves its record. All good.
- The second request then saves its record. Uh oh, now there are two Alices in the database!

If there was a database constraint as well, the second request would not be able to save its record, even though the validation succeeded.

Comment: Oh i see this makes a lot of sense. Could you explain the second part of the question in more detail? Why does simply checking another variable fix this problem (the email index)?

Comment: The database index isn't a variable - it works like a gatekeeper to make sure that any data that enters it conforms to its validations. There's simply no way of skipping it or bypassing it because it will get checked by the database at insert time, not at some time pre-insert time.

Comment: What exactly is an index for the email column? For example, he has us use the following code: `add_index :users, :email, unique: true`. Im under the impression that its just a number identification for each email, no?

Comment: Think of them like the index at the back of a book - a quick way to lookup values, and in this case we are indexing on email address. So when looking up records by email address, instead of having to process entire rows to check if the email address matches, it can just check the index to fetch the right records instead. Indexes can have constraints - in this case a uniqueness constraint. When the database updates its index (as it will for every row insert/update) it makes sure the constraint is satisfied, or it will raise an error and roll the query back.